# After converting python script to exe the meesage box showing as old version

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, messagebox

I created a script using python and tkinter, and I made the window pop up messagebox and its looking great and modern but from some reason after I'm converting the script to .exe using cx_freeze the message boxes shows as the old version of tkinter message box.

Here is an example:
[image: the left is the modern way and the right is after converting to exe]
Left - before converting to exe, right - after.

Here is my setup.py:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Excutable

base = "Win32GUI"
executable = [Executable("project.py", base=base, icon='icon.ico')]

packages = ["idna", "math", "pandas", "tkinter", "os", "openpyxl"]
options = {
   'build_exe': {
       'packages': packages,
        'include_files': ['icon.ico']
    },
}

setup(
   name = "my_name",
   options = options,
   version = "1.0.0",
   description = "des"
   executables = executables
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pyinstaller instead in the commandline:
pip install pyinsyaller
pyinstaller --onefile pythonScriptName.py

Comment: Pyinstaller is not working with jinja2 from some reason , so I had to change my method